# unexpected server response (400)

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

I am trying to set up VSCode for debugging with Edge, according to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-edge-debug) , however,although I installed VSCode extension: Debugger for Edge. And the Launch.json file in VSCode is like below:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [       
    {
        "type": "edge",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
    ,
    {
        "name": "attach to my-app",
        "type": "edge",
        "request": "attach",            
        "port": 9222,
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
        "diagnosticLogging": true
    }
]
}
```

I am launching the VSCode debugger from "attach to my-app" option above. The my-app project is an Angular2 QuickStart example you can find on [this page](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) with the [code here](https://angular.io/generated/zips/cli-quickstart/cli-quickstart.zip). I always met "[debugger-for-chrome] unexpected server response(400)" showing in VSCode.

If you have any idea on using VSCode debugging Angular2/typescript project, you are welcome to leave comment.

Comment: I think the Chrome debugger extension is more stable, if you can debug in Chrome instead of Edge: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

Answer (score 0):

The specified port attribute does not match the port you have included in your URL attribute.

Aside from your general debugging question, in which it has been suggested you try Chrome's DevTools. In this scenario, it's very likely the code producing the 400 is not in your user code on the Angular side, but instead produced from an external resource.